# Lag and lacks of accuracy using gluUnProject for object moving in a 3D space

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to move a 3D object ,using the mouse, in a 3D space.

So,I retrieve the actual matrixes and use the gluUnProject (that map window coordinates to object coordinates) to obtain the actual x,y,z from the mouse position dx and dy.

By design my project has 3 functions to translate objects,one for each axis.So everywhen happens an event like 'mouseMoveEvent' it emits a signal 'mouseHasMoved(x,y,z)'   (x,y,z obtained from gluunproject and scaled down).

This signal (QT based) is catched by the controller that invokes the three methods I spoke above.

As it is it works but there is a lot of lag,and the movement is not precise.The select object tend to go farther from the parallel plan it should stay.

Here is the sample code of 'mouseMoveEvent':

```
if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {

    gluUnProject(event->x(), -event->y(), 0, model_matrix, proj_matrix, view_matrix, &newx, &newy, &newz);

    if (event->x()>lastPos.x()){
        emit SignalPreviewMouseXChanged((float)(newx/1000));
        emit SignalPreviewMouseZChanged((float)(-newz/1000));
    }
    else {
        emit SignalPreviewMouseXChanged((float)(-newx/1000));
        emit SignalPreviewMouseZChanged((float)(newz/1000));
    }


    if (event->y()<lastPos.y())
        emit SignalPreviewMouseYChanged((float)(newy/500));
    else {
        emit SignalPreviewMouseYChanged((float)(-newy/500));
    }

}
lastPos = event->pos();
updateGL();
```

Where objCamera->mPos is the camera Position.

This sets up matrixes for gluUnProject()

```
void setMatrixes()
{
  glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model_matrix);
  glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj_matrix);
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view_matrix);
}
```

Same translation functions are linked with 3 QSliders (x,y,z) and they are accurate and fast.So that's not a function problem.Here's an example of one the methods that is called when signal is catched

```
void SlotZRotationValueChanged(float val){
  sceneRef->translate(0,0,tValue*10);
  facade->window->getPreview()->RebuildScene();
}
```

The question is: what I am doing is logically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ***partially*** (please read bottom of this) separating up\down movement from left\right: changed the above mousemove function to

```
if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
    setMatrixes();


    gluUnProject(event->x(), -event->y(), 0, model_matrix, proj_matrix, view_matrix, &newx, &newy, &newz);

    float acc=sqrt((int)dx^2+(int)dy^2);
    acc*=acc;


    qDebug()<< acc;

    if (dy<dx){
        if (event->x()>lastPos.x()){
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged((float)(newx/2500)*acc,0,(float)(-newz/2500)*acc);
        }
        else {
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged((float)(-newx/2500)*acc,0,(float)(newz/2500)*acc);
        }
    }

    else{
        if (event->y()<lastPos.y())
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged(0,(float)(newy/1750)*acc,0);
        else {
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged(0,(float)(-newy/1750)*acc,0);
        }
    }
    isPressed=true;
}
lastPos = event->pos();
updateGL();
```

while in the controller:

```
void Controller::SlotMouseTranslationValueChanged(float val1, float val2, float val3){

if (val1!=0) sceneRef->translate(val1,0,0);
if (val2!=0) sceneRef->translate(0,val2,0);
if (val3!=0) sceneRef->translate(0,0,val3);
facade->window->getPreview()->RebuildScene();
}
```

Now it has no lag and everything works fine.

**Consideration:**

*Now I am not dragging the object but using the gluUnproject to retrieve the plan on which my object can move (then calling translate function that add\sub values to object position).So where my mouse points to is different from the position of the object on my screen.*

How to achieve this result?could someone explain me the logical steps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Picking" technique for this. Check this tutorial
http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/

Comment: I am already using picking mode to select the objects,the selections is not the problem ;)